# Send activity with preference

Tags: android, android-activity, preferences

I am developing an app where i need to be able to open an activity from other classes. I have tried different Preference types, but without being able to save and load the Preferenceses. I need to be able to save an activity and then pick it up later in another class to use it.

Please help me

Comment: Can you detail your question. And if possible with some code.

Comment: It is quite hard to paste a code that makes some help. I am developing an app that needs a package name from an activity, in another class than the class finding the package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here use intent to switch classes

```
Intent e = new Intent(initial.this, next.class);
startActivity(e);
```

OP wasn't looking for this answer.

Maybe this answer:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

In here you can access either SQLDatabase lite to store data or use sharredPrefference to store small data like textsizes and such where in your other activity classes can look if it exist and do stuff when it does exist.

Difference between SharredPrefference and SQLDatabaseLite is that data is more organized on SQLDatabaselite while SharredPrefference is quick and easy to access and change.

Comment: Pretty sure this is what you are looking for.
To transfer items in different classes you can add an item in the intent via (following top code) e.putextra("Key String to be called", item(pretty much any variable will do));

Comment: I do not want to switch classes. I need to save and load an activity to and from a preference.

Comment: Now if what I said was incorrect you maybe looking at storing items in a database from another activity which you want to display in your activity. To do this you may have to redesign your .xml file to support the second view and add in the data from the SQL.

Comment: Are there any ways of using preferences instead?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as an entire view class as preference but I could be wrong. I added all my stuff in a database and call upon it with SQLDatabaseLite.

Comment: Are ther any ways of converting the outcome of an activity to text, and then save it as a standard text view?

Comment: Yes, Like I said you can save it on a database as a string using either SQLDatabaseLite or sharredPreference. Then on your new activity which you want to call back shove that text back in there. I knew my second answer was right.